# iOS - MVP how to communicate parent presenter with child presenter?

Tags: ios, swift, mvp

Situation:

1. I have a parent view which has a presenter and a child view with another associated presenter.
2. A service provides the model to parent presenter but this model has to be transferred to the child presenter too.
3. I don't want to use Notification, all communication between service and presenter will be done by delegates.

I'm currently linking both presenters through views, if the parent presenter needs to communicate something to the child it calls a method of child and if child needs to notify something to the parent (i.e a button is tapped), child uses a delegate (I'm trying to emulate what swift makes with tables). I'm using this way in order to separate both presenters.

I need to know if this procedure is wrong and, if it is wrong, why.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

I would focus on Protocol Oriented Programming. Make both the parent and child conform to a their own protocol. When initiating the child you can dependency inject the parent. The parent can hold a reference to the child. Since both conform to protocols, you will know what methods they have publicly available. This makes it also way easier when you write your tests since you can send in a mock to the child which conforms to the same protocol which in turn you can use to verify the codes behaviour.

Just keep in mind not to make any strong references to each other, otherwise you'll end up in a retain cycle.

Comment: Thanks! I understand your point of view (this was the first way I implemented), but I would like to know if what i'm doing is ethically from the point of view of architecture

Comment: It is hard to say. If you would write the suggested solution in my team and submit a pull request, I would probably reject it and ask you to make it more testable and decouple. Also, think of the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In your case, parents are dependent upon the delegate from a certain other child and visa versa. However, I can imagine that in certain team, maybe where TDD is not as important, your architectural approach would be sufficient enough.

Answer (score 0):

Overall your idea described in the question is good. I would suggest to use code blocks as callbacks instead of delegates implemented via protocols.

```
class ChildView {
    var onButtonTapped: ((someData: String) -> Void)?
    @IBAction func buttonapped(_ sender: Any) {
        self.onButtonTapped?("data from child view")
    }
}

// in parent view code space:
childView.onButtonTapped = { [weak self] data in
    self?.updateStuff(data)
}
```

This approach is better in scope of code isolation. Parent knows about the child as far as he manages it, but the child knows nothing about the parent. Also no need of any additional code outside of this functionality (like protocols etc...).